# Why max width not working in tailwind css?

Tags: css, css-position, width, tailwind-css, fixed

I have set max width to **max-w-screen-2xl** but the navbar is ignoring that and going outside the max width value. I have set **max-w-screen-2xl** for other sections and they are just workingfine. How to fix this?
[image]

```
<div className='flex items-center justify-center max-w-screen-2xl mx-auto'>
            <div className="navbar nav-container bg-base-100 max-w-[90%] w-[90%] fixed top-3 z-50 px-8 py-6">
                <div className="navbar-start">
                    <div className="dropdown">
                        <label tabIndex={0} className="btn btn-ghost lg:hidden">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-5 w-5" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h8m-8 6h16" /></svg>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button  onClick={()=>navigate('/')} className="btn btn-sm btn-ghost normal-case text-xl">daisyUi</button>
                </div>
                <div className="navbar-center hidden lg:flex">
                    <ul className="menu menu-horizontal p-0">
                        <li><a>Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="navbar-end">
                    <button onClick={()=>navigate('/register')} className="btn btn-sm">Register</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class like this `w-[100%] max-w-[800px]`. And it would work. See here for code example - https://freetailwindui.co/components/card-component-tailwind-ui-css/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34106399)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The default for max-w-2xl is set 1320px. You should customize the theme for max-x-2xl to expand it, e.g., 1500px. To do so, modify the tailwind.config.js as follows.

```
theme: {
        maxWidth: {
            '2xl': '1500px',
        },
        extend: {},
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

after the percentage number, you need to determine the value from which to calculate the percentage. at this code
'''
max-w-[90%] w-[90%]
'''

Comment: Can you please be more specific? I didn't get what you said.

Comment: if the size is indicated only as a percentage, he will not be able to understand what to calculate percentages for. Try this code max-width: calc(100% - 30px);

Comment: I just added max-w-[1280px] w-[90%]  and it's working. Thanks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).